# Why Google Home not communicating to server always?

Tags: google-home

We have implemented the Smart Home Skill for Google Home to operate the lights.

Its working sometimes i.e its taking inputs and communicating to the server and operating the lights.

where othertimes as its not reaching the server with the commands given to the google voice device.

We see that its failing most of the times.

anybody faced this kind of problem?
Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.com! Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As of now, there is no question in your post and even if we hypotesize one, there is a lot of details missing.